# How to have two PYTHONPATHS for version 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, pythonpath

I have an issue where somewhere along the line i've installed python3 and it has overwritten the default python path which is for 2.7. So when I go to terminal and type in "python" it loads version 3.6.5 instead of 2.7. If i type in "python2.7 to explicitly run python i get an error saying its pointing to the 3.6 site-packages instead of 2.7.

derekchan@PandaMacPro:~/python$ python2.7
Your PYTHONPATH points to a site-packages dir for Python 3.x but you are
running Python 2.x!
PYTHONPATH is currently: "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages"
You should `unset PYTHONPATH` to fix this.

I've viewed other threads on this issue but it doesnt solve or help my problem. Is this a simple PYTHONPATH issue?

I just want to be able to type in "python" and it load version 2.7 instead of version 3 and not have issue with the conflicting python packages.

Comment: you can try to  set an alias on your linux machne. `alias python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7`.

Comment: i've read many threads and articles that states that using alias is bad practice... will this cause python package conflicts?

Comment: even if i use the alias it still doesn't solve the problem of python2.7 pointing to the python 3 PYTHONPATH.

Comment: multiple version of python don't have different PYTHONPATH variables

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a distribution like Anaconda with built-in package management. With Anaconda you can easily isolate your Python2 and Python3 environments and not have to mess with `PYTHONPATH`

https://anaconda.org/

Comment: thats a plausible alternative. But id rather directly solve this issue rather than using a "workaround"

Comment: Its the kind of thing that keeps me up at night if you know what i mean...

Comment: IMO, using an alias or fixing `PYTHONPATH` is more of a 'workaround' compared to using Anaconda. I use Anaconda all the time and it is quite useful especially on cluster machines where I do not have privileges to install packages and it is a pain to have to deal with dependencies when I move stuff form my PC. With Anaconda I just export the environment as a YAML file and duplicate it there

Comment: im already using PyCharm that allows me to swap between 2 and 3 easily. But i often like using terminal to write my python code which is why id like to find out how to run both version without having to change the PYTHONPATH all the time.

Comment: I agree with Davin totally.  Anaconda makes it easy to run python and to create and use virtual environments which you may want to do if using Python2 and Python3 on the same machine